# Bounded Above Integral Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Given $s_{n}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
> 0 &  &x=0 \\ 
> \sqrt{n} &  & x\in\left [ \frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n} \right ]
> \end{matrix}\right.$, show that $\left\{\int_{0}^{1}s_{n}\right\}$ is bounded above.

I would think it is because as $n\to\infty$, isn't $s_{n}\to 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^{1} s_n =\sqrt n (\frac  1 n -\frac  1{n+1})=\sqrt n \frac  1 {n(n+1)} \in [0,1]$.